# wrapItem(...).trimStart in Expo and React native

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

Today I create a new project with `create-react-native-app` and after installing dependencies CRNA says to start your project with `expo start`, after running this command all thing seems good and a chrome open page `localhost:19002` but after a minute this page is stoped and in the console it says :

```
  [12:26:47] Starting project at D:\Try\eleventh
  [12:27:13] Warning: Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache 
  refresh for C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\Expo\schema-30.0.0.json: 
  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.202.142.166:443.
  [12:27:39] Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
  [12:27:39] Metro Bundler ready.
  [12:27:40] Opening on Android device
  [12:27:40] Successfully ran `adb reverse`. Localhost URLs should work on 
  the connected Android device.
  [12:27:44] Tunnel ready.
  [12:27:44] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
  [12:27:44] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)

   exp://192.168.89.2:19000





























    To run the app with live reloading, choose one of:
   [12:27:44] wrapItem(...).trimStart is not a function
   [12:27:44] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

as you see it says :

```
  wrapItem(...).trimStart is not a function
```

and this is some information may be useful :

create-react-native-app version: 2.0.2

node version: v8.11.3

expo version: 2.2.0

npm version: 6.4.0

yarn version:1.10.1

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a later version of node. I ran into this issue as well using node version 8. Bumping it with `nvm` to node 12 worked.